# Windows 10 stuck in automatic repair loop after changing boot order / booting and updating Manjaro Linux

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, manjaro

My Windows 10 install is stuck in an automatic repair loop

**Tried [this](https://www.makeuseof.com/fix-stuck-in-automatic-repair-loop-windows-10/) article with the following results**

- `chkdsk c: /r` didn't find anything
- Can't enter startup settings, just returns me to the automatic repair screen
- The command

  `C:\Windows\System32\config\\rregback* C:\Windows\System32\config\`

  Returns an error that it can't rregback isn't there
- Disabling the automatic repair tool didn't fix it, instead I am at a BSOD stating the system needs repaired with the following info

  ```
    File: \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
    Error code: 0x000000f
  ```
- And finally trying to reset Windows results in an error saying it can't do it (yes, I literally cannot even reset the system)

**In addition to this article, I've tried:**

- Running startup repair (startup repair couldn't repair your pc)
- `sfc /scannow` (completes verification, then states
  `Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation`)
- Using Ventoy running windows installation media to run the following commands:

  ```
    bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd
    bootrec.exe /fixmbr
    bootrec.exe /fixboot
  ```

How this could happen by simply reordering my boot order and messing around in / updating manjaro is beyond me.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like the update changed the boot manager and now windows is unable to correct it. Might mean a reinstall of windows. So first step should be to get your backups sorted.

Comment: How have you been running Windows commands if you can't boot?

Comment: If the OSes are installed in UEFI mode as they should be for any 10 years old  PC or newer then you can boot Windows directly in UEFI settings > Boot. Try that before anything else. Also note that "/fixmbr" is NOT applicable to modern systems.